# Media Queries for @2x, @3x, and @4x images

Tags: image, css, media-queries, retina-display

I am trying to support a variety of pixel ratios on the current site I'm developing. I also want to ensure I provide any required browser prefixes to support the widest variety of devices/browsers within reason. Also, I'm using SVG's wherever possible, but I need a solution for photographic images. Ideally, I'd like to provide:

1. @1x image (Pixel Ratio 1.0)
2. @2x image (Pixel Ratio of 1.25+)
3. @3x image (Pixel Ratio of 2.25+)
4. @4x image (Pixel Ratio of 3.25+)

My question is what would be the best way to go about writing the media queries to achieve this? My primary concern is that my arguments are correct for what I'm trying to achieve. I'd appreciate any suggestions or advice you have. Currently my code is as follows:

```css
/* @1x Images (Pixel Ratio 1.0) */
#dgst_shopping_bag {background-image:url(img/shopping_bag.png);}

/* @2x Images (Pixel Ratio of 1.25+) */
@media only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
    #dgst_shopping_bag {background-image:url(img/shopping_bag@2x.png);}
}

/* @3x Images (Pixel Ratio of 2.25+) */
@media only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 9/4),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.25),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.25),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 2.25dppx) {
    #dgst_shopping_bag {background-image:url(img/shopping_bag@3x.png);}
}

/* @4x Images (Pixel Ratio of 3.25+) */ 
@media only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/4),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.25),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.25),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 3.25dppx) {
    #dgst_shopping_bag {background-image:url(img/shopping_bag@4x.png);}
}
```

**Alternative 1:** I've been considering utilizing the `<picture>` tag to accomplish this. I know you can provide alternative content for browsers that don't support `<picture>`, which would be my primary concern in utilizing it. Do you guys think that  would be the best practice for providing photos for multiple pixel ratios?

Comment: Short question: Are your images all same width on all devices?

Comment: For the majority of devices, the image dimensions is the same. I'm merely swapping out the assets for high pixel density displays. However for the lower breakpoints, some images are smaller dimensions due to screen size limitations.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, ignoring the obvious functional differences between a background image and an inline image element such as `picture`, there are a few pros and cons between the two.

## Pros for inline image / cons for `background-image`:

There is no way to use a media-query for an inline style, so specifying a `background-image` requires declaring a selector for whatever elements require background images separate from the tag. This complicates this solution for dynamically created elements.

Also, if you are only interested in serving images with different pixel ratios, you can simply use the [`srcset` attribute of an `img` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) instead of the `picture` element. The `picture` element requires more markup and has a number of features that are unnecessary for this, plus `srcset` is slightly better supported.

## Pros for `background-image` / cons for inline image:

Resolution-based media queries [are much better supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution) than [the `picture` element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture) and [the `srcset` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset). Some browsers do not support either the `picture` element or the `srcset` attribute at this time, although support is improving.

Incidentally, if you want to maximize browser support for Firefox versions older than 16, you can add [the `min--moz-device-pixel-ratio` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio), which has the same syntax as `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`. Here is an example using your CSS.

```css
/* @2x Images (Pixel Ratio of 1.25+) */
@media only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
    #dgst_shopping_bag {background-image:url(img/shopping_bag@2x.png);}
}
```

## Best-practice?

Best practice would be to use media queries for places you need a background image, and either `srcset` or `picture` for places you need an inline image. However at this point, it may be more important to consider what browsers you need to support. For that, see the compatibly links (possibly considering that many people using older browsers are probably also using standard resolution monitors):

- [CSS media resolution](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution)
- [picture element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture)
- [srcset attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset)

Comment: did u notice dppx does not pass W3C validation tool?

Answer (score 8):

Really use the `img[srcset]` attribute. Its support is much better than state in another answer. Current Chrome **and** Safari do support this attribute. And we **know** that, Firefox 38 and IE 12 will also support it. Additionally the syntax allows you to do simple progressive enhancement and you don't need to write complex media queries.

This is how it looks like:

```
<img src="img/shopping_bag@1x.png" srcset="img/shopping_bag@2x.png 2x, img/shopping_bag@3x.png 3x" />
```

And in case you want to add support to non-supporting browsers, you can choose between [different](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) [polyfills](https://github.com/aFarkas/respimage).

In case you use a polyfill you might change the markup to this:

```
<img srcset="img/shopping_bag@1x.png, img/shopping_bag@2x.png 2x, img/shopping_bag@3x.png 3x" />
```

Comment: The reason for the larger images and ratios is because Apple's latest retina display (on the iPhone 6) requires 3x images, they also have an iMac with a 4k display on the market. The 4x image is just my attempt at being not-so-distant-future proof for 4k displays. The images are compressed as well.